# How to run Matlab in batch mode without GUI

Tags: matlab, command-line, vbscript

I have this script (`Run_Matlab_No_GUI.vbs`) which is supposed to run a MATLAB file `test.m`.

`test.m` is supposed to produce a file `test.txt`.
I run it on a windows command window.

Here is the listing:

```
# Run_Matlab_No_GUI.vbs
Set ml = CreateObject("Matlab.Application")
ml.Visible = false
ml.Execute("test.m")
ml.Execute("pause(4)")
```

```matlab
% test.m
a=1;
b=1;
c=a+b;
dlmwrite('C:\tmp\HEEDS1\test.txt',c);
```

**Problem**: it runs without errors but is not producing the `text.txt` file.

- Path to MATLAB: `C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin`
- Path to test.m: `C:\tmp\HEEDS1`

Command line is in the `test.m` folder

Answer (score 4):

You can run MATLAB in no GUi mode through

```
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r test
```

Comment: Did that. it still shows a Matlab command environment.
Ran this
"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2015a\bin\matlab.exe" -nodesktop -nosplash -noFigureWindows -r run('test.m'); end; quit

Comment: Consider adding `-nodisplay`

Comment: `-nodisplay` and `-nodesktop` are different, so try with `-nodisplay` as @Marouen suggests. You can find more information [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html).

Comment: @NaftaliHerscovici: try also putting your MATLAB command in quotes: `-r "run('test.m'); end; quit"`.